# Cloud Deploy Access to Private GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, cicd, gke-networking, google-cloud-deploy

After spending ages trying to follow https://cloud.google.com/architecture/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools and get my private worker pool to access my private GKE cluster, I managed to get it working.

However, I'm now trying to use Cloud Deploy to deploy workloads to my private GKE cluster. Since Cloud Deploy doesn't use my Cloud Build private worker pool, it can't leverage the connectivity between the worker pool and the GKE. Is there a way to make Cloud Deploy access a private GKE? I'm not finding anything online for that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible! To do so, you will need to configure an [execution environment](https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/execution-environment) to specify the private work pool you would like use. You can find more details, here:

https://cloud.google.com/deploy/docs/execution-environment#changing_from_the_default_pool_to_a_private_pool